# Angular Translate translateChangeSuccess invoking multiple time,

Tags: angularjs

Could you please anyone help me on angular translation, my application contains some text static and some text that are dynamic and on change language it request to api with the language key then i get the dynamic text. so how should i implement?

I have implemented static translation with partial loader for static text.

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
$translateProvider.useMissingTranslationHandlerLog();
$translateProvider.useCookieStorage();
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
            'urlTemplate': 'Views/{part}-{lang}.json'
        });
        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('Home/Index');
```

for dynamic text the requesting from server, I use the angular translate event which is,

```
var remove = $rootScope.$on('$translateChangeSuccess', 
function(event,   data) {
//calling the service to get the dynamic data.
} 
$scope.$on('$destroy', remove);
```

but the issue is its get invoked multiple time and my application performance degrading.

Please help if there any other best way to implement this using angular translate pascalprecht for static and dynamic content on the site.

Comment: Where are you setting up the listeners? In a controller? Directive? Component?

Comment: In a controller

Comment: Did you found solution for this @PunitSudakar?